# Populate rows (year listing) based on drop down selection MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, search-indexing, list, dropdownlist

I have a challenge presented to me. I have searched quite a bit, but I cannot find a solution that exactly works.

I have a drop down listing that represents the number of years (1-50). I need to populate the number of rows based on the number of years chosen from the drop down listing (1-50). For example; if a user selects "7", seven rows are populated, and each row corresponds to the next incremental year (populated rows start with current year and ends with drop down selected year. 2023 + 7 = 2030.

Does this make sense?

Suggestions?

Thanks for your help!

Tried MS Excel's VLOOKUP function, INDEX function, VBA modules, etc. Nothing that I have tried quite works how we want the resulting table to populate.

Answer (score 0):

In new versions of Excel you can use a formula with SEQUENCE function, e.g.

```
=SEQUENCE(A4+1,,2023)
```

`A4` contains the number of years chosen from the list. However if you start from the current year the number of rows will be 1 more than you expected.